# I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 on a dual boot machine, and now I have very little disk space. What to do?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, disk-usage, reinstall

I installed Ubuntu for the first time half a year ago, so I'm a fairly new user.

Back then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 with a dual boot setup, with Ubuntu being the default OS. A month ago I encountered a problem, which I could not find a solution to, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu from a bootable USB. Luckily, Ubuntu found that it was already installed and suggested to just overwrite the current installation of Ubuntu with a fresh one, which I of course selected.

Ubuntu works fine, but I don't have a lot of space, and I've had several warnings saying that `The volume “filesystem root” has only XX MB disk space remaining.` I have removed any unnecessary files to free up space, until I realized that my "main" drive is not mounted.

When I run `df -h` in a terminal, it outputs the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   19G   16G  2.1G  89% /
tmpfs           7.7G   12M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop1      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop2       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop3       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop4      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop5       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop6      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop7      144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop10      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop8       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop11      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop12     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop13      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop14     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop15      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop16     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop17      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop18     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop19     174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/34
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   34M  223M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           1.6G   52K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

When I open Disk Usage Analyzer, I see the following:

[Overview of disks in Disk Usage Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RK9G.png)

where the "106 GB Volume" used to be my "main" hard drive, where I had many of my programs, pictures etc, and by default it is unmounted. When I click it to mount it and run `df -h` again, it outputs the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   19G   16G  2.1G  89% /
tmpfs           7.7G   25M  7.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop1      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop2       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
/dev/loop3       36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop4      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/loop5       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop6      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop7      144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop10      54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop8       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop11      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
/dev/loop12     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop13      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop14     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
/dev/loop15      35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
/dev/loop16     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop17      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop18     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop19     174M  174M     0 100% /snap/spotify/34
/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   34M  223M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           1.6G   48K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p7   97G   61M   92G   1% /media/william/633b2560-ee34-420d-84bb-138f68537887
```

where the 106gb drive is now added (I deleted everything on it, hence the usage %).

When restarting the computer, the drive is unmounted once again.

My question is: How can I make this drive my "main" drive once again, automatically mounted when the computer is booted and automatically the drive applications are installed onto, instead of the root, which (as far as I'm concerned) should only be used for system critical files and applications. This was not a problem before I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Please tell me if I need to provide any more info.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that an old /home that you did not mount when reinstalling or just a data partition. Either way you should mount using fstab, but a lot different if /home or  a data partition. Whether different drive or another partition on same drive, if just data: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Thanks. I followed the guide created by OP in the second link, and I succesfully reformatted and mounted my partition automatically.